# Parametric Differentiation Proof

Tags: calculus

For parametric differentiation, $\displaystyle\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{\frac{dy}{dt}}{\frac{dx}{dt}}$.

Let $x=f(t)$ and $y=g(t)$

Then, by the chain rule: $\displaystyle\frac{dy}{dt}=\frac{dy}{dx}\cdot\frac{dx}{dt}$

Now, from here, some textbooks same something along the line as "this calculation is valid if $f(t)$ and $g(t)$ are differentiable, $f'(t)\neq 0$,and $f'(t)$ is continuous" which makes sense to me.

But, then they will say something like "the inverse $t=f^{-1}(x)$ exists and the composite function $y=g(f^{-1}(x))$ is a differentiable function of $x$". I am having a bit of a hard time understanding why we are bringing up an inverse function in the proof for a derivative.

I am aware that $\displaystyle(f^{-1})'(x)=\frac{1}{f'(f^{-1}(x))}$.

Thanks in advance. Sorry if it is obvious and I am just overlooking it.